# code-push auto rollback in cordova app on android device

Tags: android, cordova, code-push

**description:**

I use code-push in a cordova project.On Android device, when I call `codePush.sync`, the updated package will be downloaded and installed correctly(no error) and I can see all the changes.But when I resume to the app next time, all the changes are gone and the app rollback to old version.

**how I sync:**

```
if (window.codePush) {
  const InstallMode = window.InstallMode;
  window.codePush.sync(syncCallback, {
    deploymentKey: window.device.platform === 'Android' ? CODE_PUSH_KEY.android : CODE_PUSH_KEY.ios,
    installMode: InstallMode.IMMEDIATE
  });
}
```

**how I release:**

`code-push release-cordova block-chain-android android --deploymentName ${environment} --des "${description}" --targetBinaryVersion "^2.0.0"`

**what's possibly going wrong:**

**cordova run the different index.html in the different path.**

**when the app was first installed:** 01-02 19:30:19.719 15422-15422/? D/CordovaWebViewImpl: >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)

**And then the update was installed and restarted:** 01-02 19:31:55.424 15422-15422/? D/CordovaWebViewImpl: >>> loadUrl(file:/data/user/0/com.test.testApp/files/codepush/deploy/versions/62b60c3f481e89c83d5fd6d7f215133aa16bf800cde246f0453f073224e55e52/www/index.html)

**Finally the app was resumed after we did see the changes:** 01-02 19:32:18.029 15422-15422/? D/CordovaWebViewImpl: >>> loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html)

**related versions:**

- cordova-android: 6.4.0
- cordova-plugin-code-push: 1.11.16

---

**Did I miss anything after the package was downloaded and installed, like `tellCodePushToCopyIndexHtml`**

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I forget to call `codePush.notifyApplicationReady()` in the `deviceready` like `document.addEventListener('deviceready', () => { window.codePush.notifyApplicationReady() }, false);`

Comment: didn't worked for me. using it with vuejs.
``
document.addEventListener("deviceReady", function(){
codePush.sync();
codePush.notifyApplicationReady();
}, false);
``
facing same problem as you.